# What kind of line is formed when a piece of paper is folded?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

**What kind of line is formed when a piece of paper is folded?**

I am 17, and I'm homeschooled. I have a book from 1958 that's called "Plane Geometry, Welchons Krickenberger Pearson" It has no answers in the back of the book.

I found this question in the beginning of the book, and I tried asking my parents, and I researched it on the internet, and I came up with no solution.

1) I need to know what the Geometry question is asking.

2) What do I need to know to solve this problem.

I would really appreciate your help. This is my first time posting on here, I will look into the posting rules in depth today. It sort of sounds like what dimension is the line.

Thank you,

Sebastian

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  Please include the question in your post.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I just added it :)

Comment: The question is kind of vague. Is there absolutely no more information?

Comment: Do you mean that "What kind of line is formed when a piece of paper is folded?" is the actual question in the book? It is completely unclear to me what that even _means_. Unless the answer is "a **straight** line" because that is what the fold itself is (assuming you lay your folded sheet of paper flat).

Comment: Perhaps they are looking for the response "a line segment", but it could be something else too.

Comment: Perhaps it is an allusion to the dragon curve! Consider reading Jurassic Park, OP.

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context? In what regard do they talk about different kinds of lines?

Comment: Does the line change the dimension from 1D to 2D? When the paper is folded? Does it turn into a curved line?

Comment: @Aurey The 10 questions that is near this question mentions: intersection, how many lines through 1, 2, and 3 points, if two lines intersect can they intersect again, etc... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose from common knowledge the book is trying to introduce some elementary concepts of straightness.

A straight line is formed when a piece of paper is folded. The new straight line forms along the fold with two parts of paper on either side of the fold or line.

Comment: Yes, it's introducing elementary concepts. How did you come to that conclusion? Does the line turn into a curved line?

Comment: Just guessing it as you mention it was at the beginning of book. To get to curvature  concept of a line may be you have turn some 20 pages or so more after introduction to  concepts of circle, its circumference,$ \pi$, area &c..

Comment: Thank you very much! I will move on. Very interesting! I chose your answer as the most helpful!

Comment: Welcome. More guessing than math !